# Find which thread currently owns a lock so I can kill it

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking, clr

I need to find out which thread currently owns the lock.

I'm writing a multithread server using ThreadPool that hosts independent application instances. When shutting down an application instance I call Monitor.TryEnter to either acquire the lock or timeout. If a timeout occurs I need to get which thread owns the lock so I can abort it.

If there are no bugs in the applications I would never need to do this as each worker would lock and unlock the application instance on entry and exit to the application. But if there IS a bug, and for whatever reason the worker doesn't exit and is either deadlocked or stuck in an endless loop I want to be able to kill that thread and application instance, while letting the rest of my server live on. The application instance at this point is a lost cause.

Seems like a pretty straight forward requirement, but couldn't find anything built in to do it.

One workaround would be to add a Thread member in the same context as the lock and have each thread update it as it acquires the lock. But that relies on everyone ALWAYS remembering to update it when a lock is acquired.

Comment: Nononononono... Aborting threads is only going to make a bad situation worse. Don't do this! You need to find out why the thread is snarled up, and **fix the problem**

Comment: How is it possible that a critical lock can be acquired by a resource you don't control? Could you elaborate please? You should wrap the lock in your own lock implementation that forces a timeout and never exposes the true underlying lock.

Comment: It is unclear why you think you need to do this.  The CLR is already quite capable of killing a threadpool thread at process exit without your help.  It is automatic, a TP thread has its IsBackground property set to true.

Comment: I'm not currently having issues with deadlocks/endless loops, because as you've pointed out its all my code and I should be in control of it.

What I'm trying to achieve is preventing either a deadlock or endless loop in an application instance from impacting the entire system.

Comment: If the application instance is buggy and lost cause, then killing it will most likely leave your system in inconsistent state. That's why you shouldn't do that.

Comment: @svick What exactly do you mean by _leave your system in inconsistent state_. State inside the borked application instance, or the internal CLR state.

Comment: @Mark The state that's the reason you're using the lock.

Answer (score 0):

You think the thread control as a top down hierarchy, but this is not the right way of thinking in the matter of multithreaded applications. If a Thread has a timeout or something else went wrong during its execution, the thread itself has to take care of releasing the lock and ending itself.

Comment: So is it not possible then to handle the case of one application instance throwing itself into an endless loop and sucking up a worker thread until the server is restarted ? 

Ideally the thread should never get itself in such a state, but if it does I'd like the extra protection of being able to kill it.

Comment: @Mark: Killing a thread leaves your process in an indeterminate state.  The only safe thing to do is exit the process.  The OS is designed for process isolation, not thread isolation.